# ContinueWith not being called async

Tags: c#, android, .net, asynchronous

I'm trying to httpget some values before I execute the next line in the statement. I need to wait for this call to return so I can use the values I deserialize into a list.

Since I want the async call to finish first, I wrapped this in a `Task`. It worked and it's successfully retrieving the JSON. I then can't get it to go into the `ContinueWith` block. Why is it not going in there, even when the task is completed(?).

How I'm calling it:

```
Task f = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var task = RetrieveDataAsync();
            }).ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {
                pokemonListActivityListView.Adapter = new PokemonListAdapter(this, pokemonList);
                pokemonListActivityListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
                pokemonListActivityListView.ItemClick += PokemonListActivityListViewOnItemClick;
            });
```

RetrieveDataAsync method:

```
private async Task RetrieveDataAsync()
        {
            string dataUri = "http://pokemonapp6359.azurewebsites.net/Pkmn/GetAllPokemon";
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(dataUri, string.Empty));


                //DisplayProgressBar(BeforeOrAfterLoadState.Before, progressBarView);
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                //DisplayProgressBar(BeforeOrAfterLoadState.After, progressBarView);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    pokemonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonDTO>>(content);
                    //canPressButtons = true; //fix this when implement local db

                    Utilities.Utilities.ShowToast(this, "Successfully fetched data", ToastLength.Short, GravityFlags.Center);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    Utilities.Utilities.ShowToast(this, "Failed to fetch data", ToastLength.Short, GravityFlags.Center);
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
```

Why is my code not going into the `ContinueWith` when I've got the JSON ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just assigning the hot task, you are not waiting on it to finish. You have to call `ContinueWith` on that task:

```
var task = RetrieveDataAsync();
task.ContinueWith( ... );
```

Or await the task:

```
var result = await RetrieveDataAsync();

... // continue
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're ignoring the task returned from `RetrieveDataAsync`. If you *return* that task from your lambda expression, then it will behave as you expect.

On a side note, you shouldn't use `ContinueWith`; it's a dangerous API. Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`:

```
await Task.Run(() => RetrieveDataAsync());
pokemonListActivityListView.Adapter = new PokemonListAdapter(this, pokemonList);
pokemonListActivityListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
pokemonListActivityListView.ItemClick += PokemonListActivityListViewOnItemClick;
```

Comment: Any further Information why ContinueWith is dangerous? Thx

Comment: @leon22: The [problems with `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) are the same as [`StartNew`'s problems](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html): no understanding of `async`, surprising default scheduler behavior, and has a simple, built-in replacement (`await`).